# Why would one want to use string.Format with only one parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

I encountered the following code string in a project's code:

```
var result = string.Format(source);
```

with variable 'source' being a string

I can't understand what useful this line is doing. As I always thought, we need at least two parameters for string.Format method to have some useful output.

ReSharper is not highlighting this as a something redundant so it seems that this line might have some purpose which I can't grasp at the moment. (Or maybe ReSharper just doesn't handle this case specifically)

Why would one want to use string.Format with only one parameter?

Comment: That overload isn't listed on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @Vladislav to introduce a latent bug exploited when `source` will contain a format sequence. Bradley, overload with variable number of arguments, they can go from 0 to N. I saw this too and, at least in that case, it was an orphan of original code.

Comment: @maccettura You can't add static extension methods as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Addidtional arg parameters are mark by params keyword - so you don't need to provide any one of them. By the way string.format without parameters is totallu useless and redundant.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, it is. It's the one taking `params object[] args` after the format.

Comment: @maccettura This is not custom extension method, GoToDefinition gives me

    `public static String Format(String format, params object[] args);`

as a call target.

Comment: Is the project in source control?  Can you view the history of the file and see if that line perhaps ever contained other parameters?  Could be that it's had something no longer needed refactored out without catching that the entire function call is now redundant.  Failing that, you'll have to go ask whoever wrote it.

Comment: My best guess would be that it is a vestige of multiple code edits, over multiple years, by multiple developers, who were not fully paying attention to what they were modifying.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I went throught Git repository, original SVN repository, several branch merges only to found that this line was originally added with only one parameter. Luckily, that developer is still working on the project, so I will have a chance to ask him tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the overloaded function

```
public static string Format(string format, params object[] args);
```

is allowing that code to compile. I cann't imagine that `string.Format(source)` would be helping in any meaningful way.

Comment: I tried to remove this line and solution was built without issues. Looks like that this line indeed has no purpose.